# Exposed bulb/wiring project

Tags: safety, lighting, grounding

Apologies if this is the wrong exchange.

I would like to start a home project, in which screw-in bulbs are left mostly exposed, and connected to semi-flexible wire. Something similar to [this](https://www.ingo-maurer.com/en/products/birds-birds-birds):

[image]

[A closer shot](https://www.ingo-maurer.com/en/products/lucellino-table), from a different peice shows the concept a little more clearly:

[image]

I'm very new to electronics, and intend to invest plenty of time into learning before I begin the project properly, but I'd like to know whether making the bulb-wire connection safe (as I assume/hope it is in the links provided) for others to be around/touch (interested kids, pets, etc) is beyond the reach of an amateur like me. Surely this is beyond simple grounding? If so, and if anyone knows what direction I should be going, I'd be very appreciative for any input.

Cheers!

Comment: Questions on all stack exchange sites are required to stand on their own.  You must use the edit button to re-write this so that someone can understand what you are doing and the specific problem you are asking a question about without clicking any of your links - those can only be used to provide supplemental material, not as the core of the question itself.  Without this, your question will quickly be closed.

Comment: Thank you.. rewriting now. Haven't the foggiest how to word this though! :P

Comment: @user3255322 - I embedded some imgs for you, should be a good start to making this more on topic. p.s.: "Birds Birds Birds" should probably be replaced on the question.

Comment: If you look at the technical data it says the bulbs are special and it has a mains to 24V transformer. Now whether you call 24V is safe is another thing, but the bulb end is effectively "low" voltage. It also says not good for high humidity environments where you will likely get a tingle out of them.

Comment: @WesleyLee thank you! I'm getting some extra wording together :)

Comment: The key to this would be finding low voltage "bulbs" (quite possibly LEDs imitating incandescents)

Comment: @Trevor thanks for the input! As a complete novice, I completely missed the 24v mention in the description. Small shocks I'm OK with, and humidity is something I haven't seen in the arse end of England for a long time :) project is starting to look good for a go!

Comment: @ChrisStratton Cheers! The search is on.

Comment: I seem to remember the UK was all humidity .. Recall weather man saying "Good news the rain will stop tomorrow and be replaced with showers." once.

Comment: @user3255322 - Low voltage lamps as Chris said, enameled wire, some conformal coating after soldering. Won't be fail proof but better than completely exposed.

Comment: Ah yes, I remember him too. We had him flogged for that lie. 
I found the bulbs I think! [link]https://edisonlightglobes.com/Shop/shop/fittings/festoon-lights/24v-1-5w-led-2200k-gls-festoon-bulb/ would these do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting project. The good news is that the answer you want is no:

making the bulb-wire connection safe (...) for others to be around/touch (interested kids, pets, etc) is **NOT** beyond the reach of an amateur.

I said "an amateur". If you'll be the amateur who can do this is another thing. :-)
Let's see.

Their site says that they use an exclusive lamp: "With special halogen bulb 35 W, produced exclusively for IngoMaurer GmbH, only for use in the Lucellino product family. Luminous flux: 600 lm, light efficiency: 17 lm/W, output: 35 kW/1000 Std. 2000 h, CRI 100, EEC C. Socket E27. The bulbs are mentioned as exception in the EU regulation 244/2009."

I would try another kind of approach, and would not use AC. Obviously it wouldn't be just like the professional item, but would be more feasible. And more safe, although the risk of broken glass is the same as the original thing.

Now, the part of the answer that IS NOT about electrical engineering.

- Use old glass lamps; hollow the bulb as shown [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Oyule-Lamp/)
- Apply mate varnish to the bulb. There is craftmanship varnishes that can be applied to glass.
- Use bare 18 AWG copper wire; normal wire stripped of the cap; apply a coloured varnish to the wire.
- Inside the lamp, use a cluster of warm-light leds, rolled with tissue paper. The led circuit can be lighted with single cells. The leds could be [these](https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/2M-20-LED-Battery-Operated-LED-Copper-Wire-String-Lights-for-Xmas-Garland-Party-Wedding-Decoration/32807135128.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10152_10065_10151_10068_10344_10345_10342_10343_10340_10341_10540_10307_10060_10155_10154_10056_10055_10054_10539_10538_10537_10059_10536_10534_10533_100031_10099_10103_10102_5590020_10052_5640020_10053_10107_10050_10142_10051_10173_10084_10083_5370020_10080_10082_10081_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10312_10313_10314_10078_10079_10073-10110,searchweb201603_17,ppcSwitch_5&btsid=b7d74794-dd38-4664-b011-f73b5d3fa7e8&algo_expid=8d326c79-6a04-4d28-9b75-26f9def6fbe7-35&algo_pvid=8d326c79-6a04-4d28-9b75-26f9def6fbe7).
- The AWG 18 wire would hold the lamp; at the bottom of the lamp, the leds' wire would be connected to the external wire. After the connection, you would use epoxi glues to hold everything.
- you still need to provide the wings.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for such a thoroughly detailed answer! I was working in a house that had one of these installed and it looked incredible. I've been looking at hollowing bulbs out for another project... the "eternal terrarium" https://youtu.be/N5r9CJ_MJBc so should be ready when the time comes. With regards to the AC-DC aspect, are you suggesting a transformer? Or running off batteries. I've seen some cheap transformers that might do the trick. Excellent idea with the tissue paper. I'm pretty sure that's going to be exactly the light style I'm looking for.

Thank you again mguima!

Comment: And thank you for the idea! I think that I'll try to do something like this. I've been keeping old lightbulbs for years and I've already filled some with micro-gardens (that weren't eternal). For the AC-DC parts, if you're not experienced with electronics, don't bother, you could start with an old cell-phone charger, and add resistors to keep the led from burning out. It's simple and you'll find hundreds of tutorials online about wiring a led and a resistor to a power source.

Answer (score 1):

This custom design appears to use 24Vac halogen small bulbs inside large Edison style bulbs. So 24Vac is safe but  the wire is special for strength. Perhaps insulated tinned steel wire, which may be hard to find.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm getting my shopping list together now.

Comment: The biggest expense is transformer for 22 * ? Watt bulbs and this seems like overkill and blinding to look at.  Something does not look right for dim bulb and power rating.  Look for low 12Vdc Frosted LED bulbs instead